# Hydraulic fluid velocity

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics

in a pic like this would the speed of liquid at the inlet change anything ?

[image]

Comment: Actually, it's very clear what the OP is asking.  However, his question is more of an engineering question rather than a physics question.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a positive displacement pump.  Assuming that it is, the speed of the liquid at the inlet is directly related to the rotational speed of the gears, which are directly related to the speed of the liquid at the outlet.  Without more information regarding piping diameters on the inlet and outlet, and the trapped volume around the gear teeth, the exact speeds of all associated variables cannot be determined, but it is known that if you double the speed of the liquid at the inlet, all other speeds will double.